# How to add third party reporter in mocha?

Tags: javascript, gruntjs, code-coverage, mocha.js

I want to add a third party reporter in mocha.
https://github.com/mochajs/mocha/wiki/Using-mocha-programmatically

In above link its saying to select a reporter like below:

```
var mocha = new Mocha({
    ui: 'tdd',
    reporter: 'xunit'
});
```

xunit comes in bundle with mocha. Now I want to add 'istanbul' or 'lcov' reporter to add in mocha. How can I do it?

Answer (score 2):

You have to install your reporter via npm first. If you have installed mocha globally, you also have to install your reporter globally.

```
npm install mocha-lcov-reporter -g
```

Then, you have to add the path of your reporter in the task:

```
var mocha = new Mocha({
  ui: 'tdd',
  reporter: './node_modules/mocha-lcov-reporter'
});
```

I have not tried this example, but I think it works.